# How well does my function fit data?

Tags: fitting

Oleksandr Karsten suggested me to mark the difference between this question and the one that is already answered: in the other question it is calculated a `FittedModel` to some data. In my question I want to know how to verify that the empirical expression I found "fits" my data.

I'm trying to find the best fit to some data that I generate with fortran. [image: Green line corresponds to my empirical function, while the orange line is the theoretical function]

Theoretically the data must obey the law I*Sin[x/2]^-2, where I=constant/area. So I used `NonlinearModelFit[[data, (a*m*\[Sigma]) / (l*r)^2*Sin[x/2]^-2, a, x]` to determine the "a" out of my data (I know the other parameters and this corresponds to the orange line). This fitting function  has many marvelous options like "BestFitParameters" to test the 'goodness of fit' which allows me to corroborate the theoretical model.
Empirically, I found an expression that fits, al least visually, perfectly well my data (green line): `m*\[Sigma] / (45.4*l*r^2)`. What I need to determine is if this empirical expression really fits my data (percentage of discrepancy, for instance). Could you tell me how to accomplish this task?

Comment: Use `NonlinearModelFit[]` instead of `FindFit[]`. It has a plethora of fitness checking options already built-in

Comment: The problem is not using 'FindFit[]' or 'NonlinearModelFit[]', but to determine if my empirical function does fit the data. I seek for a criteria to decide whether the function is correct or not. Can you help me?

Comment: Antonio, Modeling can tell us how closely the data fit the function, but it does not, and cannot, tell us "whether the function is correct or not".  In that sense, models are approximations.  Furthermore, there will inevitably be conditions under which the model "breaks down", i.e. ceases to provide a satisfactory description of at least some aspects of the phenomenon.

Comment: @DavidCarraher Very good writeup.

Comment: @David I greatly appreciate your answer and the previous answers as well. I wonder if there is a way I can say that my function comes, say 95% "close" to my data. Can I use Mathematica for this?  I also thought to generate values with the function corresponding to the 'x" values of my data and compare them. Does Mathematica have an intrinsic procedure for this?

Comment: Antonio, Take a look at :http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html    and also http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html   "AdjustedRSquared" will tell you how much overlapping (shared or common variance) there is between your data and your model.  It is a measure of goodness of fit.  You can also obtain confidence intervals.

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz you might want to peruse CrossValidated.SE, since it sounds like you are interested in validating statistical methods.  Once you have an idea of which validation tool fits your purposes, we can help you implement that method in Mathematica.

Comment: David, You put me on the track I was looking for. Thank you so much for your support. Cheers

Comment: @bobthechemist thank you so much for your advise. I'll try your idea too. Cheers-